# Best way to handle Undefined array key in PHP 8.0

Tags: php, key, undefined

I upgraded to PHP 8.0 a few months ago and like a lot of developers I'm having trouble with this notice turned into a warning. I don't understand the proper way to deal with this so I'd like to know how to fix this without bloating my code.

Previously I would do this:

```
public function myFunction($options = []){

    //we know $options is an array, so let's check if the key is there and get its value at the same time
    if($run = $options['run']){ 
            
        //do something with $run
            
    }
}
```

$options is initialized as an array and if key 'run' is defined I get its value ready to be used. What it's being suggested I handle with this simple piece of code now is...

```
public function myFunction($options = false){

    if(isset($options['run']){

        $run = $options['run'];
            
        //do something with $run
            
    }
}
```

It seems to me like this is adding an extra unneeded step: is it really how it should be handled?

Answer (score 21):

You can do this to avoid typical if/else block

```
$run = $options['run'] ?? null;
```

To know more details https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary

Comment: This solution is not backward compatible. Any other way?

Comment: This is compatible since PHP 7.0 but still much less readable in simple cases like `if (!$_POST['delete'])`. If this is the best "official" solution, I'll use the `@` prefix for all array accesses now. PHP gets worse with every version. Not much and its advantages over proper application environments like ASP.NET Core with C# have all vanished.

Answer (score 1):

You can suppress the error by appending "@" before the expression. $run will be null if the key doesn't exists:

```
if($run = @$options['run']){ 
    //do something with $run   
}
```

[Error Control Operators (php.net)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: Supressing the error message DOES NOT STOP THE ERROR HAPPENING. So this is a basically bad idea in almost all cases

Comment: In practice this is a shortcut that works very well in a simple case like this: array['string']. I don't see what problem this could cause? The result is either null or the requested value.

Comment: In case the $options becomes an instance of a class, this would crash the code, you would never see the error, bad idea

Comment: The error is not silenced : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type A as array. (with PHP 7.2). Also with PHP 8 more errors are displayed with this operator https://php.watch/versions/8.0/fatal-error-suppression

Comment: This is a very bad practice. The answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/70549387/1797452) is the way to go.

Comment: This is the best way for array accesses where the key might not be set. PHP is a dynamic scripting language, not a statically-typed programming language. Not even JavaScript generates anything near a warning and just gives you `undefined` when a property doesn't exist. The only possible "error" that can happen here is that the key does not exist, but that's exactly the non-error I want to ignore and use the `null` value instead. This has worked perfectly in the past, let's keep it that way or choose another language with less typing effort.

Comment: I'm upvoting the answer involving "@" error suppression because I am interested in whatever value is returned by the key and not if the key exists or not (for which I would use other methods, anyway) Something like this wouldn't be possible with ternary isset: 
$quantity_totals[$item->item_id]=@$quantity_totals[$item->item_id]+$item->item_quantity;